# Calls to /events/ returning error: "This operation does not support binding to a non-calendar folder."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When making this GET request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{EVENT_ID}?%24select=id%2Csubject%2Ccategories%2CseriesMasterId",
```

The Graph API is returning HTTP 400 with the details below. I am unable to find documentation explaining this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{ 
  "code": "ErrorInvalidRequest",
  "message": "Your request can't be completed. This operation does not support binding to a non-calendar folder.",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "8b92c8b2-3b52-4640-998f-cc07e56bdc27",
    "date": "2019-04-26T21:17:18"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update: This behavior seems to happen when querying for the status of an event that has been deleted by a user. Would be great for Microsoft to document this behavior -- assuming this is in fact intended.